Aravis + Python + Docker takes no pictures
I’m just starting to use Aravis and I’m stuck trying to get the Python libary to work.
My system is a Docker (ubuntu:latest) container running over Windows 10 with WSL2. I have a HIKVision GigE camera connected on my local network and I can see it from inside the container (via ping).
I believe everything is properly installed, because from my init code:
self.cam = Aravis.Camera.new(self.ip)
self.stream = self.cam.create_stream(None, None)
self.device = self.cam.get_device()
print(f"Camera vendor : {self.cam.get_vendor_name ()}")
print(f"Camera model  : {self.cam.get_model_name ()}")
print(f"Pixel format  : {self.cam.get_pixel_format_as_string()}")
print(f"Stream: {self.stream}")
print(f"Device: {self.device}")

I can get these variables:
Camera vendor : Hikrobot
Camera model  : MV-CS200-10GC
Pixel format  : BayerGB8
Stream: <Aravis.GvStream object at 0x7f2025103c80 (ArvGvStream at 0x25c11a0)>
Device: <Aravis.GvDevice object at 0x7f2025109680 (ArvGvDevice at 0x1f49830)>

When I launch my code, this fragment:
payload = self.cam.get_payload()
self.stream.push_buffer(Aravis.Buffer.new_allocate(payload))
self.cam.start_acquisition()
image = self.stream.timeout_pop_buffer(10000000)
data = image.get_data()

Gives the following error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_data'

If I use a non-timeout function, I’m stuck forever waiting for the buffer to pop.
What might be going on here? Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

prototype this without docker, without WSL2. scrounge up a linux live system on a USB drive or something.

aravis-python has a binary release for windows. try that maybe.
